# Cómo realizar varios select (inner join) y sumar cada campo de cada tabla en particular

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas con campos que tienen el mismo nombre. Lo que necesito hacer es una sola consulta (procedimiento almacenado) y extraer la suma total únicamente de cada campo por tabla. Es decir:

Tabla 1 tiene el campo cantidad y posee 3 registros. 10 | 5 | 4 | total = 19

Tabla 2 también tiene el campo cantidad pero posee registros diferentes. 4 | 6 | 2 | total = 12

Tabla 3 tiene el campo cantidad con diferentes registros. 9 | 1 | 5 | total = 15

Al momento de realizarlo por separado me da el total de manera correcta, pero me han solicitado por temas de rendimiento hacerlo en una sola consulta, y al momento de sumarlo me dan resultados distintos.

Ejemplo de consulta por separado:

```
select tpd.`cantidad` as reserva from `tabla_1` as tpd where 
`codigo` = '123' and `area` = 'metropolitana';
```

Como se puede apreciar en la consulta de arriba, lo he realizado únicamente por una tabla, y así lo hago por cada una (tabla1, tabla2, tabla3). Vale decir que tengo 3 procedimientos almacenados distintos, y la idea es hacerlo en uno solo.

Aquí un poco de código de la consulta realizada en una sola con las distintas tablas en juego:

```
select sum(tsc.`cantidad`) as reservaA, sum(tpc.`cantidad`) as reservaB, sum(tpd.`cantidad`) as reservaC
from `tabla_3` as tsc
 inner join `tabla_2` as tpc on tpc.codigo = tsc.codigo and tpc.almacen = tsc.almacen
inner join `tabla_1` as tpd on tpd.codigo = tsc.codigo and tsc.almacen = tsc.almacen
where tsc.`codigo` = '123' and tsc.`almacen` = 'metropolitana' and tpc.`codigo` = '123' and tpc.`almacen` = 'metropolitana' and
tpd.`codigo` = '123' and tpd.`almacen` = 'metropolitana'
```

Al ejecutar ese script, me da la suma total de las reservas con otro resultado más elevado. Al parecer suma algunos duplicados.

Comment: Y las relaciones entre las tablas es 1 a 1??? si no, obviamentete va a dar de mas...

Comment: Recordatorio al margen: si no es código HTML/CSS/JS ejecutable en la pregunta, no lo coloques como _snippet_.

Comment: @gbianchi la verdad es que el problema radica en que se van duplicando los registros. En la tabla_1 tengo solo 1 registro, en la tabla_2 tengo 3 por poner un ejemplo, entonces como que completa los espacios vacíos en registro duplicados. En la tabla_1 si existe  un solo registro como el 5, y en la tabla_2 existen 3 registros con valores  4 | 3 | 5, se repite 3 veces el 5 en la tabla 1 y por eso da un valor mayor.

Comment: Entonces, tenes que hacer primero las sumas, y despues el join... si no, sql no hace magia... hace las cosas en el orden que le decis... que es primero el join, y despues sumar...

Comment: @gbianchi pues en el código sale que eso hice, hago primero las sumas con la funcion sum() y luego los inner

Comment: no.. en tu sql, primero se hacen los joins... SQL no ejecuta en ese orden ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Por qué no hacer uso de `UNION`?

```
SELECT t1_total_cantidad, 
       t2_total_cantidad, 
       t3_total_cantidad
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(cantidad) AS t1_total_cantidad, 
           NULL AS t2_total_cantidad, 
           NULL AS t3_total_cantidad
    FROM tabla_1
    WHERE codigo = '123' AND almacen = 'metropolitana'

    UNION

    SELECT NULL, 
           SUM(cantidad), 
           NULL
    FROM tabla_2
    WHERE codigo = '123' AND almacen = 'metropolitana'

    UNION

    SELECT NULL, 
           NULL, 
           SUM(cantidad)
    FROM tabla_3
    WHERE codigo = '123' AND almacen = 'metropolitana'
    
) AS t;
```

Tu consulta no funciona porque al efectuar un `INNER JOIN` estás, como sospechas, repitiendo los registros. Por ejemplo:

```
-- tabla_1
+--------+----------+
| codigo | cantidad |
+--------+----------+
| 123    |        5 |
+--------+----------+
| 123    |        6 |
+-------------------+
| 124    |        1 |
+--------+----------+

-- tabla_2
+--------+----------+
| codigo | cantidad |
+--------+----------+
| 123    |        8 |
+--------+----------+
| 123    |        9 |
+--------+----------+
```

Si realizas la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT t1.cantidad AS t1_cantidad, 
       t2.cantidad AS t2_cantidad
FROM tabla_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN tabla_2 AS t2 ON t2.codigo = t1.codigo
WHERE t1.codigo = '123'
```

Obtendrás:

```
-- "Por cada registro en la tabla 'tabla_1' cuyo código sea '123', 
-- busca en la tabla 'tabla_2' aquellos registros cuyo código coincida 
-- con el código del registro en la tabla 'tabla_1'"
+-------------+-------------+
| t1_cantidad | t2_cantidad |
+-------------+-------------+
|           5 |           8 |
+-------------+-------------+
|           5 |           9 |
+-------------+-------------+
|           6 |           8 |
+-------------+-------------+
|           6 |           9 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Si ahora sumas cada columna ―`SUM(t1_cantidad), SUM(t2_cantidad)`― interpretando el resultado como que es la suma de las cantidades en la tabla "tabla_1" en la primera columna y la suma de las cantidades en la tabla "tabla_2" en la segunda columna, será incorrecta.

Comment: Me ha servido bastante muchas gracias, está funcionando como debería :D saludos!!!